# False positives with typing and linters for async gRPC server using Python

Tags: python, grpc-python

As can be seen in the [hello world example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/async_greeter_server.py) when you implement a gRPC service in Python using the asyncio API you define `async def` methods. However, the base clase you are extending has non-async methods, like in the [base class for the same example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py#L29). That base class is autogenerated by `protoc` and I haven't found any options to generate an async base class. As a result I get errors like the following:

- pylint: `W0236: Method 'FooOperation' was expected to be 'non-async', found it instead as 'async' (invalid-overridden-method)`
- mypy:  `error: Return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]" of "FooOperation" incompatible with return type "Iterator[FooOperationResponse]" in supertype "Foo"  [override]`

This is not a problem at runtime, and the code works ok. As a workaround, I can disable type checking and linting for those methods by adding the comment `# type: ignore  # pylint: disable=invalid-overridden-method` to each method, but that makes those static analysis less effective. Is there a proper way to do this? Ideally some option or tool so the generated base class uses `async` methods.

Thanks